# Aggregate by counting the distinct value with datetime constraint

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two python pandas dataframes, in simplified form they look like this:

DF1

```
+---------+---------+------+-------+
| Date_in | Date_out| Group| Item  |
+---------+---------+------+-------+
| 1991-08 | 2000-08 |   A  |   A1  |
| 1991-08 | 2021-02 |   A  |   A2  |
| 1997-02 | 2021-02 |   B  |   B1  |
| 1998-03 | 2001-03 |   C  |   C1  |
| 1999-02 | 2002-02 |   D  |   D1  |
| 2000-09 | 2021-02 |   D  |   D2  |
| 2000-03 | 2001-04 |   D  |   D3  |
| 2001-08 | 2021-02 |   D  |   D4  |
+---------+---------+------+-------+
```

DF2

```
+---------+---------+-------+
|  Date   |  Group  |  Item |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 2000-06 |    A    |   A1  |
| 2000-06 |    A    |   A1  |
| 2000-07 |    A    |   A1  |
| 2000-07 |    A    |   A1  |
| 2000-07 |    A    |   A2  |
| 2000-07 |    B    |   B1  |
| 2000-08 |    D    |   D3  |
| 2000-08 |    D    |   D4  |
| 2001-05 |    D    |   D1  |
| 2001-05 |    D    |   D2  |
| 2001-05 |    D    |   D3  |
| 2002-04 |    D    |   D2  |
| 2002-04 |    D    |   D2  |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

1. I want merge DF2 by `Date` & `Group` and count how many distinct values of item in DF1, if the dates in the new merged DF lie between datetime constraint of DF1,
2. And, How many distinct items exist based on datetime constraint in the new merged DF (I think it is solved by @Rick_M's answer)

Desired output

```
+---------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|  Date   |  Group  |      Total_item_1      |       Total_item_2    |
+---------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| 2000-06 |    A    |            2           |            1          |
| 2000-07 |    A    |            1           |            1          |
| 2000-07 |    B    |            1           |            1          |
| 2000-08 |    C    |            1           |            0          |
| 2000-08 |    D    |            3           |            2          |
| 2001-05 |    D    |            3           |            3          |
| 2002-04 |    D    |            2           |            1          |
+---------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Appreciate any comments and feedback, hope I've served the idea more clearly

Comment: I've read this a number of times, and can't seem to understand what you're asking for. The `Total_distinct_item_B` column almost looks like `dfb.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Date','Group']).nunique()`, but it's not clear to me what is happening in the `item_A` column. Maybe you can elaborate further, possibly making it less simplified/generic?  Also, changing the `dfa` to `df1` and `item_A` to `item_1` might help, as you're using `A` and `B` elsewhere.

Comment: I hope I've served the idea more clear here @RickM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure I understand your question because I don't reproduce the same "desired output" (is there possibly an error above?), but even if not I'm hoping this will still be helpful to you.

Your data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('1991-08', '2000-08', 'A', 'A1'), ('1991-08', '2021-02', 'A', 'A2'),
 ('1997-02', '2021-02', 'B', 'B1'), ('1998-03', '2001-03', 'C', 'C1'),
 ('1999-02', '2002-02', 'D', 'D1'), ('2000-09', '2021-02', 'D', 'D2'),
 ('2000-03', '2001-04', 'D', 'D3'), ('2001-08', '2021-02', 'D', 'D4')], columns=['Date_in','Date_out','Group','Item'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('2000-06', 'A', 'A1'), ('2000-06', 'A', 'A1'),
                 ('2000-07', 'A', 'A1'), ('2000-07', 'A', 'A1'),
                 ('2000-07', 'A', 'A2'), ('2000-07', 'B', 'B1'),
                 ('2000-08', 'D', 'D3'), ('2000-08', 'D', 'D4'),
                 ('2001-05', 'D', 'D1'), ('2001-05', 'D', 'D2'),
                 ('2001-05', 'D', 'D3'), ('2002-04', 'D', 'D2'),
                 ('2002-04', 'D', 'D2')], columns=['Date','Group','Item'])
```

Changing fields to be datetime type:

```
df1['Date_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_in'], format="%Y-%m")
df1['Date_out'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_out'], format="%Y-%m")
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format="%Y-%m")
```

We can drop duplicates from df2 immediately:

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates().copy()
```

...and then groupby `Date` and `Group`, to get what I think is your `Total_item_2` column:

```
tmp1 = df2.groupby(['Date','Group']).nunique().rename(columns={'Item':'Total_item_2'}).reset_index()
print(tmp1)
        Date Group  Total_item_2
0 2000-06-01     A             1
1 2000-07-01     A             2
2 2000-07-01     B             1
3 2000-08-01     D             2
4 2001-05-01     D             3
5 2002-04-01     D             1
```

For the next part, I'll leave various intermediate steps so that you can inspect what is happening. You could combine some of these steps if you wanted to.

Merge `df1` with this new result dataframe, and create a `valid_date` column that is `True` if the date satisfies the constraint:

```
tmp = pd.merge(df1, tmp1[['Date','Group']], on='Group', suffixes=['_1','_2'], how='left')
tmp['valid_date'] = (tmp['Date']>=tmp['Date_in']) & (tmp['Date']<=tmp['Date_out'])
```

Then only use the rows with a valid date, and do a similar groupby to what we did earlier:

```
tmp2 = tmp[tmp['valid_date']].groupby(['Date','Group'])['Item'].nunique().reset_index().rename(columns={'Item':'Total_item_1'})

print(tmp2)
        Date Group  Total_item_1
0 2000-06-01     A             2
1 2000-07-01     A             2
2 2000-07-01     B             1
3 2000-08-01     D             2
4 2001-05-01     D             2
5 2002-04-01     D             2
```

Finally, you can merge `tmp1` and `tmp2` together (and reorder the columns):

```
result = pd.merge(tmp1, tmp2, on=['Date', 'Group'])
result = result[['Date','Group','Total_item_1','Total_item_2']]

print(result)
        Date Group  Total_item_1  Total_item_2
0 2000-06-01     A             2             1
1 2000-07-01     A             2             2
2 2000-07-01     B             1             1
3 2000-08-01     D             2             2
4 2001-05-01     D             2             3
5 2002-04-01     D             2             1
```

Comment: Thanks @Rick_M for your comprehensive answer, I would try it first

Comment: IT WORKS DUDE, YOU MADE MY DAY!! Thanks anyway